# Calling static function template within dependent scope

Tags: c++, generic-programming, function-templates, class-template

Suppose I have a static function template `template<int I> void ft()` within a struct template `template<bool B> S`, and I want to call `ft` from another function template `template<bool B> void g()`, passing the bool template parameter from `g` to `S`:

```
template<bool B>
struct S {
  static void f() {
  }
  template<int I>
  static void ft() {
  }
};

template<bool B>
void g() {
  S<B>::f();
  S<B>::ft<12>();
}

int main() {
  g<true>();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this in GCC 4.5.2 gives two errors about the line `S<B>::ft<12>()`:

1. *expected primary-expression before ')' token*
2. *invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'*

Comeau ( http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/ ), in strict C++03 mode, also complains about that line, stating *"expected an expression"*, with a caret just below the closing parenthesis. Neither compiler complains about the line `S<B>::f()` however, and Comeau can actually compile the whole minimal example in relaxed mode.

If I remove `g`'s template, and instead instantiate `S`'s template parameter in `g` like so:

```
void g() {
  S<true>::ft<12>();
}

int main() {
  g();
  ...
```

GCC successfully compiles it, as does Comeau in strict C++03 mode.

From GCC's second error above, it seems that there is an ambiguity in the interpretation of `S<B>::ft<12>`, as if it thinks I'm trying to test if `S<B>::ft` is less than 12. I'm aware of the use of `typename` to resolve ambiguities that arise when referring to types within dependent scopes. Does anyone know how to resolve the ambiguity when the thing that appears in a dependent scope is a function, not a type?

Comment: Needs more `template`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: Thanks, the post you linked to is very informative!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to help the compiler a bit, with telling it that ft is a template, like this:

```
template<bool B>
struct S {
  static void f() {
  }
  template<int I>
  static void ft() {
  }
};

template<bool B>
void g() {
  S<B>::f();
  S<B>::template ft<12>();
}

int main() {
  g<true>();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick! I've just noticed that the C.13.6 "Template as a Qualifier" section of Stroustrup's C++ Programming Language book describes the same thing. Thanks for your help!